# How to use both Run Keyword If and Run Keyword and Return Status?

Tags: robotframework

```
file.robot
Keyword1
       log  this is keyword1
       ${some_value} =  Set Variable    Hello, world!
       [Return]   ${some_value}

file2.robot
Some_name
        Run keyword If    'True' == 'True Run Keyword and return Status   Keyword1
```

I want to use this way. How do i access the return value in file2.robot

```
Above, 'Some_name' in file2.robot calls the 'Keyword1', the return value 'some_value' to be printed in 'Some_name' of file2.robot.
```

How can it be achieved in one-liner as stated above ?

Comment: Except for a missing single quote and a missing space, it looks like you're already doing it. What are you asking for that this code doesn't do?

Comment: @BryanOakley : How do i receive/print the ${some_value} in file2.robot ?

Comment: @Verv : Based on certain condition, I'll have to run a keyword that returns a value. That value has to printed in called keyword. In simpler, a one-liner.

Comment: @BryanOakley : 'Status' here, might be something status of the keyword. But, i'll have to print the return value in the calling keyword.

Comment: So, you need both the status (pass/fail) plus the result of whatever `keyword 1` returns? Instead of speaking in generalities, can you be a bit more specific on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley : Run Keyword If if val1 == val2 [Choose appropriate keyword here, i'm not sure - Run keyword and return status or could be something else] Keyword1. If the 'Return_Value' == 'expected value' Log some message , if Return_value == something_else Log some other message. I cannot, embed these last two conditions in Keyword1, beacause comparing values will be different for different scenarios.

Comment: I can't read any of that comment. If you want to add some clarification, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a "Run keyword..." command and both get a return value and a pass/fail value. However, if all you need is the return value, `Run keyword if` will return the result of the keyword that it runs.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${the_value}=  run keyword if  'True' == 'True'  keyword 1
```

With the above, `keyword 1` will only run if the expression evaluates to true. `${the_value}` will be set to the result of `keyword 1`.

If you need both the status and the returned value, you can use `Run keyword and return status` to run the keyword, but you'll have to modify the keyword to set a suite or global variable that your test can get after the keyword returns.